# What are the colored/highlighted edges in edit mode?

Tags: mesh, vertex-groups, edges

There are red and pink edges on my mesh.

What do these colored edges mean? How can I use them?

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Those edges have been marked.
There are actually five types of markings you can apply to edges:

1. **Red** - UV Seam
2. **Blue** - Bevel Weight
3. **Purple** - Edge Crease
4. **Cyan** - Sharp Edge
5. **Green** - Freestyle Edge

You can mark edges yourself from Edit Mode using the *Edge* menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>).

[image]

*Colors in Blender 2.79:*

- *Red* - UV seam
- *Orange* - Bevel weight
- *Pink* - Edge crease
- *Blue* - Sharp edge
- *Green* - Freestyle edge

Comment: What happens if an edge has multiple markings? One takes precedence for display?

Comment: @ajwood [Here you go](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/177335/). Six years later, but still :).