# How to get rid of purple lines-crease on an object?

Tags: modeling

Does anyone know how I can get rid of that crease? Is there any possibility to make it a smooth face like the other faces? I am modeling a cup of coffee (online tutorial) and when duplicating the interior side to create the liquid I get that look at the level of the areas where the handles rise from. Even so, after duplicating, I am not sure if there is any way to get rid of that and make it a smooth object overall. (You can see the purple lines too)

(Beginner here :D )[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: [What are the colored/highlighted edges in edit mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/what-are-the-colored-highlighted-edges-in-edit-mode)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get rid of the crease, first select the purple edges. Then, in the *sidebar* (with the cursor in the 3D Viewport, press <kbd>N</kbd> to toggle it), set the *Mean Crease* value to zero.

[image]

Thats it!

Comment: Thank you very very much. You are a life saver!

Answer (score 2):

Select the edges and adjust the **Edge Crease** by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, followed by pressing <kbd>0</kbd> and confirming it with <kbd>Enter</kbd> to set it to 0(essentially removing the Edge Crease).

Comment: As of version 2.82, you'd have to press *Shift + E* followed by -1, to dial the crease back from 1 to 0. *Shift + E* > 0 makes no change to the crease value.