# Select part of mesh, teal object in edit mode

Tags: mesh

Does anyone know how I would select only the folded part of the wing easily (not selecting every face) (maybe something like the A keyboard shortcut for select all but just for the wing)? I tried L with limited success. And why is the plane teal/blue in edit mode?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). The cyan edges are marked as sharp. [What are the colored/highlighted edges in edit mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10580/78972)

Comment: You can use *Ctrl+L* to select all faces of separated mesh. Hard to tell if it's the case here :).