# How to deactivate the red lines

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am following a tutorial to create a 3D model. Then I accidentally pressed a button and the edges turn red. It is hard to see and how can I deactivate it? Thank You.[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/what-are-the-colored-highlighted-edges-in-edit-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With default theme, these red lines are seams (cuts for UV unwrapping).

[image]

To get rid of it, in edit mode: select all and clear seam.

<kbd>A</kbd>

<kbd>U</kbd> then *"clear seams"*