# How do I make these green lines in edit mode the default color?

Tags: vertices, faces, edges

The edges are a green color which make it hard on my eyes to edit this particular object.
I was wondering how to return the color of these to default?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the colored/highlighted edges in edit mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/what-are-the-colored-highlighted-edges-in-edit-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by looking for any buttons that said edge while in edit mode on this specific object. lol
[image]

This is how I got rid of the green outline on this object in edit mode.