# How do I get rid of the blue outline on my mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I was following CrossMind Studio's beginner's tutorial, specifically the pencil modeling part and got stuck after duplicating the mesh and hitting "separate". So now there's a blue outline on this new object and I can't edit it at all, or rather it can't be selected.
[image]

The video tutorial in question: https://youtu.be/cdgJaMGx6XM?t=3178

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/what-are-the-colored-highlighted-edges-in-edit-mode

Comment: You'll have to go back into Object mode (TAB), select the separated object, then go back into Edit mode to be able to edit it. At the moment you still have the original pencil selected by the look of it.