# What do red edges mean?

Tags: edges

I was doing the donut tutorial and I noticed these red edges. I thought they might be marked as crease, so I selected the edges around the green X and selected Tag Crease, since I found on google that the edges might be marked. Evidently, the marked edges are something different. I tried searching "red edge" on google, but they all mentions seams. There are no modifiers. What do the duller red edges mean?

Edit 1: This other question ([What are the colored/highlighted edges in edit mode?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/what-are-the-colored-highlighted-edges-in-edit-mode)) mentions colored edges. The answer also mentions seams. I created this question specifically because the linked answer only mentioned seams. As can be seen in the comment, the dull red lines are not seams, as U > Clear Seam has no effect.

Edit 2: The other answer does not provide an explanation for other colors nor an explanation of how other colors can be obtained by the user.

[image]

Comment: Hello they are probably seams, press U and Clear Seam?

Comment: @moonboots I selected one of the dull red edges, pressed U, and Clear Seam, but it had no effect. Additionally, I just pressed U without any edges selected, and Clear Seam, but it had no effect.

Comment: Or Edge Crease? N panel > Item > Edges Data > lower the Mean Crease down to 0?

Comment: @moonboots Lowering the Crease to zero has removed the color. Thanks. I do not know how I increased that value, however.

Comment: Maybe you've accidentaly pressed Ctrl E > Edge Crease